# Using a single parameter from a Super class where the super class uses more parameters

Tags: java

this might be something really easy to address but I am really new to Java and I am having a problem fixing this error. I am working on a basic ATM Machine (I can't go fancy just yet). I have a BankAccount class, a Checking Account (extends bankAccount), A savingsAccount class (also extends bankAccount) and a User class. In my CheckingAccount class, I want to use one of the parameters from my SUPER class (bankAccount), "balance" but I am not sure if there is **a way to only use ONE parameter from a constructor that has more than One parameter. If so, any clue for how to?**  I am getting an Error : "no suitable constructor found for BankAccount(double)..." .  This is my code so far, I appreciate your help.

-- BankAccount Class --

```
package atm;

public class BankAccount {
    public double balance; 
    public int accountNumber = 333220; 
    public User user;  
    public BankAccount(){
        balance = 0; 
    }

    public BankAccount(double balance, int accountNumber, User user){ 
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
        this.user = user; 

    }

    public void accountNumber(){
        accountNumber++;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void deposit (double amount){
        balance += amount; 
    }

    public void withDraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;  
    }

    public double getBalance (){
        return balance;  
    }

    public void transfer( BankAccount other,double amount){
        withDraw(amount);
        other.deposit(amount); 
    }


}
```

-- CheckingAccount Class --

```
package atm;

public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
    private int transactionCount;
    private static final double transactionFees = 1.50; 
    private static final int freeTransactions = 5; 


    public CheckingAccount (double balance){
        super(balance); //HERE is where I am confused. I only need to use the "balance" 
        transactionCount = 0; 
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){
    transactionCount ++; 
    super.deposit(amount); 
    }

    public void withDraw(double amount){
    transactionCount ++; 
    super.withDraw(amount);
    }
    public void deductFees (){
    if (transactionCount > freeTransactions){
        double fees = transactionFees * (transactionCount - freeTransactions); 
        super.withDraw(fees);
    }
    transactionCount = 0; 
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, to invoke any constructor or method, you must pass a suitable argument corresponding to each of its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another constructor in `BankAccount.java` that only initializes `amount` like below

```
public BankAccount(double balance){ 
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

Read about having multiple constructors in Java here

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html

Comment: Thanks, Pankaj! Using multiple constructors definitely helped me out to get rid of my error. I read that this is no the best coding practice though, Do you think it represents a further risk for the application to run or not in my case being this a very basic Java exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Since `CheckingAccount` is a `BankAccount`, it must have all the attributes of the `BankAccount`, including the account number and the `User` who owns it.

The base class requires `accountNumber` and `user` to be supplied by the derived class, so you should change the constructor to forward this information to `super`:

```
public CheckingAccount (double balance, int accountNumber, User user){
    super(balance, accountNumber, user);
    transactionCount = 0; 
}
```

**Note 1:** In certain situations a derived class could hard-code parameters to be passed to `super`; this is *not* one of these situations.

**Note 2:** Consider making `BankAccount` abstract, and changing accessibility of its constructor from `public` to `protected`.

Comment: Thank you! I will do some research on how to change classes to abstract and from *public* to *protected*.   :)